# Processing french response taking time

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I have a stream as below .I am getting french response from http-api i see lot of time difference .I am using some message converter  for utf-8.

If the response from http  is english I see that it process in 5 min for french its  20 min.Not sure if http-client  or json processor taking time or json creation taking time.

file|xml-parser-processor|custom-http-client|json processor>queue

queue>http-client|processor| >queue2

My http client is like below

```
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean  id="batchRestTemplate" class="test.batch.httpclient.BatchRestTemplate" >
   <beans:constructor-arg name="requestTimeOut" value="${requestTimeOut}"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="maxConnectionPerRoute" value="${maxConnectionPerRoute}"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg name="totalMaxConnections" ref="${totalMaxConnections}"/>
```

```
 <int-http:outbound-gateway id='batch-http'  header-mapper="headerMapper"
                               request-channel='toHttp'
                               rest-template="batchRestTemplate"
                               url-expression="payload.contains('${filterAttribute}') ? '${url1}' : '${url2}'"  http-method="${httpMethod}"
                               expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
                               reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>


public BatchRestTemplate(Integer requestTimeOut,Integer totalMaxConnections,Integer maxConnectionPerRoute) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  {
          super(createBatchHttpRequestFactory());
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters= new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.addAll(getMessageConverters());
        messageConverters.add(0,new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

}
```

My processor

```
  JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(payload.getPayload());
            byte[] msgCont = convertMsgContToBytes(jsonData);


String emailRequest = new JSONObject(
                                generateEMailRequest(payload, actualRecord))
                                        .toString();
                        result = MessageBuilder.withPayload(emailRequest)
                                .copyHeaders(payload.getHeaders())
                                .setHeader(MESSAGE_TEXT, msgCont).build();




    private byte[] convertMsgContToBytes(JSONObject jsonData)
            throws EmailSMSProcessorException {
        byte[] msgCont = null;
        if (null != jsonData) {
            try {
                msgCont = jsonData.getJSONObject(MSG_CONTENT).toString()
                        .getBytes(UTF_8);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error in converting Msg Content to Byte[]", e);
                throw new EmailSMSProcessorException(e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Error in converting Msg Content to Byte[]", e);
                throw new EmailSMSProcessorException(e);
            }
        }
        return msgCont;
    }



private void validatePayload(Message<String> payload, String actualRecord)
            throws EmailSMSProcessorException {
        if (null != actualRecord) {
            JSONObject jsonData = null;
            try{
                jsonData = new JSONObject(payload.getPayload());
            }catch(Exception e){
                throw new EmailSMSProcessorException(
                                                     "payload/mandatory data is missing",CONST_SYS_EXPTN);
            }
            validateErrorIdText(jsonData);
        } else {
            throw new EmailSMSProcessorException(
                    "payload/mandatory data is missing",CONST_SYS_EXPTN);
        }
    }


private EmailRequest generateEMailRequest(Message<String> payload,
            String actualRecord) throws EmailSMSProcessorException {
        EmailRequest emailReq = null;
        if (null != actualRecord) {
            JSONObject jsonPayload = new JSONObject(payload.getPayload());
            JSONObject actualJSON = new JSONObject(actualRecord);

            emailReq = new EmailRequest();
            MessageRecipients messageRecipients = new MessageRecipients();

            if (jsonPayload.has(MSG_CONTENT)) {
                JSONObject msgCntJson = jsonPayload.getJSONObject(MSG_CONTENT);
                if (msgCntJson.has(SUBSTI_CONTENT)) {
                    String substitutionContent = jsonPayload
                            .getJSONObject(MSG_CONTENT).get(SUBSTI_CONTENT)
                            .toString();
                    JSONObject substitutionContentJSONObj = new JSONObject(
                            substitutionContent);
                    messageRecipients.setSubstitutionKeyValueData(
                            substitutionContentJSONObj);
                }
            }

            Recipient recipient = new Recipient();
            recipient.setEmailAddress(isNullCheckMandatoryFields(
                    actualJSON.getString(CNTCT_PNT_ADR_TXT),
                    CNTCT_PNT_ADR_TXT));
            messageRecipients.setRecipient(recipient);

            MessageKeyValueData messageKeyValData = new MessageKeyValueData();
            messageKeyValData.setAlertType(isNullCheckMandatoryFields(
                    actualJSON.getString(ALRT_TYPE_CD), ALRT_TYPE_CD));
            messageKeyValData.setAlertTrackingId(isNullCheckMandatoryFields(
                    actualJSON.getString(DLVRY_ID), DLVRY_ID));
            messageKeyValData.setIsDraft((getMessageProperties()!=null && getMessageProperties().getEnvironmentVar()!=null && !getMessageProperties().getEnvironmentVar().equalsIgnoreCase(ENVIORNMENT_PROD))?true:false);
            messageRecipients.setMessageKeyValueData(messageKeyValData);

            MessageEml message = new MessageEml();
            String templId = actualJSON.getString(TMPL_ID);
            String chnlType = actualJSON.getString(CHNL_TYPE);
            String msgFormat = jsonPayload.getJSONObject(MSG_ATTRIBUTE)
                    .get(MSG_FORMAT).toString();
            message.setTemplateId(
                    templId + UNDER_SCORE + chnlType + UNDER_SCORE + msgFormat);

            message.setUseDraftTemplate((getMessageProperties()!=null && getMessageProperties().getEnvironmentVar()!=null && !getMessageProperties().getEnvironmentVar().equalsIgnoreCase(ENVIORNMENT_PROD))?true:false);
            MessageRecipients[] messageRecipientsAry = new MessageRecipients[1];
            messageRecipientsAry[0] = messageRecipients;
            String substitutionKeyValueData = jsonPayload
                    .getJSONObject(MSG_CONTENT).get(TMPL_CONTENT).toString();
            JSONObject substitutionKeyValueDataObj = new JSONObject(
                    substitutionKeyValueData);

            emailReq.setMessageRecipients(messageRecipientsAry);
            emailReq.setMessage(message);
            emailReq.setSubstitutionKeyValueData(substitutionKeyValueDataObj);
        }
        return emailReq;
    }
```

Update 2:

This is not with any french or english.Its on msg size as my http-client  son output bigger payload this happens.For 2 kb its  fast  like 30k msg per min and 2k msg per min if msg size is 26 kb.Is it because of serilization? below is code where i construct  json and send to output channel as string.I am passing response again in header message header also has 26kb same from http1 response

Update 3
I was passing payload  header with my http response which is 26 kb.I removed it now i see very good performance almost matching as before.

Should i compress my header and send using kyro+ deflate zip?

Also CPU is high